# Understanding flow in recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x

Finding it tricky to wrap my head around recursion and would greatly appreciate some insight.
I am trying to understand flow in recursion by successively diving a number by 2.

```
def divide_by_2(num):

    if num > 1:
       divide_by_2(num // 2)
       print(num)
    print(num % 2,num)

divide_by_2(39)
```

output:

> 1 1
>
> 2
>
> 0 2
>
> 4
>
> 0 4
>
> 9
>
> 1 9
>
> 19
>
> 1 19
>
> 39
>
> 1 39

Questions I have are

1) Shouldn't 1 39 be printed first, why is it being printed right at the very end? Why is the order inverted?

2)Which of the two print statement should be executed first and why?

Comment: pythontutor.com visualization always helped me with this kind of issue. It is really helpful. Give it a shot http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take your code (and add line numbers for clarity)

```
1 def divide_by_2(num):
2    if num > 1:
3       divide_by_2(num // 2)
4       print(num)
5    print(num % 2,num)
```

Then run through a smaller number line by line as an example

```
divide_by_2(4)
```

> (call 1, num==4) Line 2 is executed, it is greater than 1 so move to
>   line 3
>
> (call 1, num==4) Line 3 calls the same function. It will not continue
>   to line 4 until the function call 2 is finished executing and returns.
>   We have not yet called a print statement so nothing shows!
>
> (call 2, num==2) Line 2 is executed, it is greater than 1 so move to
>   line 3
>
> (call 2, num==2) Line 3 Recurse through the same function again will
>   not continue executing until call 3 is finished. Still no print
>   statement
>
> (call 3, num==1) Line 2 is executed, it is equal to 1, move to line 5
>
> (call 3, num==1) Line 5 We finally have a print statement! We are at
>   the innermost call with num==1 so "1 1" is printed. Now that this
>   function has finished, we return to line 4 in the most recent call
>   which in this case is call 2
>
> (call 2, num==2) Line 4 With the function returning, we start
>   executing the next line which is print(num) which simply print "2"
>
> (call 2, num==2) Line 5 We have another print statement, this one
>   prints "0 2". Now that call 2 is finished executing, call 1 resumes
>
> (call 1, num==4) Line 4 prints "4"
>
> (call 1, num==4) Line 5 prints "0 4"
>
> Execution ends
>
> This gives the end result of:
>
> 1 1
>
> 2
>
> 0 2
>
> 4
>
> 0 4

The key thing to remember as to why the numbers are printed from smallest to largest is that the flow in this program prints the statements **after** recursing into the next function. This leads to the behavior call 1 -> call 2 -> call 3 -> print from call 3 -> print from call 2 -> print from call 1.

The easiest way for me to get a handle on recursion is to go through the code line by line either on paper or in my head. I hope this breakdown helps.

Answer (score 2):

Take your finger and follow the lines of code (starting with the bottom line as it’s the thing that kicks everything off), every time you encounter the divide_by_2, jump back to the top

You’ll notice that you start off heading into the function with 39, and you hit another call to divide_by_2 before you print anything.

You’ll keep going like this until you get down to 1, at which point you’ll skip over the call to divide_by_2, and then you start printing things, in reverse order as the call stack unwinds

Things unwind because when you come back out of a function call, the code continues from the next line after the function call

The next line is a print statement, so the first thing to be printed is the smallest division result

It would probably greatly help your understanding to use a language that has an interactive debugger facility so you can single step the code and see it working, but if you don’t have that, think of it like multiple levels of code indenting:

```
divide_by_2(64)

print(64)



divide_by_2(64)
  divide_by_2(32)

  print(32)
print(64)
```

Each time you recurse, you copy paste a divide/print pair into the middle blank line, in and the indent increases to demonstrate the call stack getting longer

```
divide_by_2(64)
  divide_by_2(32)
    divide_by_2(16)

    print(16)
  print(32)
print(64)


divide_by_2(64)
  divide_by_2(32)
    divide_by_2(16)
      divide_by_2(8)
        divide_by_2(4)
          divide_by_2(2)
            divide_by_2(1)
            print(1)
          print(2)
        print(4)
      print(8)
    print(16)
  print(32)
print(64)
```

You asked which print prints first, and that one is simpler if your talking about the fact that your code contains two print statements- the one that occurs first in the source code.

If you mean why does the 39 print last, it’s because your code recourses all the way in as deep as it can go before it stops recursing, and the printing is done on the way out. If you printed before you recursed into the divide function, then the numbers would start at 39 and get smaller

Answer (score 1):

Start with a smaller number so you can map all the recursions at once. I'm also going to slightly re-write your function for ease of reproducibility

```
def divide_by_2(num):
    if num == 0:
        return  # we're done
    divide_by_2(num//2)
    print(num)
```

Now we divide by 5...

```
divide_by_2(5)
-> divide_by_2(2); print(5)
-> divide_by_2(1); print(2); print(5)
-> divide_by_2(0); print(1); print(2); print(5)
-> return; print(1); print(2); print(5)
```

Basically: since you've put the recursive call before the rest of the function, it must complete its recursion before it can continue.

Answer (score 1):

Since 39 is > 1, it is going into the initial `if` statement. The first line of code in that block tells it to recursively call itself with `divide_by_2(num // 2)` (taking the integer Floor). There is no print statement hit - it just put another `divide_by_2` on the call stack, `divide_by_2(19)`. As such, this will continue to keep on adding to the call stack, and calling *no* print statements until `num` is < 1.

At the top of the call stack, you get `1 1` because that call is *not* going into the `if` conditional, it is going immediately to `print(num % 2,num)`.

After that, it comes back down the call stack where each function can execute (and finish) both the `print(num)` and then `print(num % 2, num)`, until there are no more functions to execute on the stack.

Hope that explained the 'theory' behind it a little bit.